# Execute nexe compile with gulp task

Tags: node.js, gulp

Could someone advice how to execute nexe compile by gulp task? I wrote simple gilpfile.hs file. How to add nexe.compile() there?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nexe

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const ts = require("gulp-typescript");
const nexe = require("nexe");

const target = {
    folder: "target",
    js: "index.js",
    exe: "index.exe"
};

gulp.task("build", function () {
    return gulp.src("src/**/*.ts")
    .pipe(ts({ outFile: target.js }))
    .pipe(nexe.compile()) // What write here?
    .pipe(gulp.dest(target.folder));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nexe doesn't have direct gulp support - so it doesn't work with filestream. 
But its promised based - so you can run pointing to actual file path.

The idea is - after you finished compiling typescript to js - run `nexe` build using that `target.js` file -

Try following

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const ts = require("gulp-typescript");

var { compile } = require('nexe');

const target = {
    folder: "target",
    js: "index.js",
    exe: "index.exe"
};

gulp.task("build", function () {
    return gulp.src("src/**/*.ts")
    .pipe(ts({ outFile: target.js }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(target.folder));
});

gulp.task('nexe', function () {
    return compile({
        input: target.folder+ '/target.js'
    }).then(() => {
        return true
    })
})
gulp.task('default', ['build', 'nexe']);
```